# Prove that if $4^n-1$ is divisible by $5$, $n$ must be even

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, proof-explanation

I know that with the given problem, *n* must be even, but I'm not sure how to go about proving it.

I thought at first that it could of been proven with induction and I worked out the base case that if $n = 2$, $4^2 - 1 = 15$, which is divisible by $5$. But I wasn't really sure if induction was the right way to prove it since $n + 1$ would be $3$, and $4^3 - 1$ equals $63$.

If induction is the correct way to prove it, what was the correct way to use induction?

If I'm supposed to use a different method to prove it, which do I use and how does the method work?

Comment: Hint $\pmod 5$, we have $4\equiv-1$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your approach is fine in proving that if $n$ is even then $4^n-1$ is divisible by $5$.  You have the base case, now you can assume $5|4^k-1$ with $k$ even and show $5|4^{k+2}-1$ because $5|4^{k+2}-4^k$.  This is the converse of what you were asked to prove, but it is useful.  You were really asked to prove that if $n$ is odd, $5$ does not divide $4^n-1$.  Having shown it works for even $n$, you can then say that for odd $n$, $4^n-1=4\cdot 4^{n-1}-1=3\cdot4^{n-1}+(4^{n-1}-1)$ and the last term is divisible by $5$ while the other is not.

Answer (score 3):

Since $4=5-1$ we get from the binomial theorem
\begin{align}
4^n-1&=\left(5-1\right)^n-1\\
&=\underbrace{\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}{n\choose k}5^{n-k}(-1)^k}_{\text{It is a multiple of 5}}+(-1)^n-1
\end{align}
So, for $n$ odd $4^n-1$ gives remainder $-2$ or $3$ under division by $5$. While $n$ even implies that $4^n-1$ gives remainder $0$ under division by $5$.

Answer (score 1):

$4^{2k+1}-1=4^{2k}4-1=(16)^k4-1=(**6)4-1=(**4)-1=**3$ Not divisible by $5$..

$4^{2k}-1=4^{2k}-1=(16)^k-1=(**6)-1=**5$  divisible by $5$..

Answer (score 0):

Your $n$ should be of the form $2k$.

So the next $n$ i.e. $n+1$ should be $2k+2$.

The induction will then go as usual.

**An Alternative proof by Congruence goes as follows:**

$$4\equiv -1 \pmod 5$$
$$4^n\equiv (-1)^n \pmod 5$$
$$4^n - (-1)^n \equiv 0 \pmod 5$$

So $$5 | 4^n - (-1)^n$$
For even $n$, we have that $$5 | 4^n - 1$$